# save button does not work joomla

Tags: php, joomla

i have two layouts one default.php and one - edit.php
in default view i have a link to edit one + insert id

```
<td><a href="index.php?option=com_searchtour&view=searchtour&layout=edit_one&cid=<?php echo $order['id'];?>"><?php echo $order['username'];?></a></td>
```

everything works fine but save button/delete buttons dont work. also i cannot retrive info in my second view(edit.php)
in default.php everything works fine, maybe i wrote a wrong link

Comment: Are you refering to the "save" button in the Joomla backend for components? If so then the code for them goes in the view.html.php

Comment: more detail required to help - like code, error messages, joomla version, front-end or back-end etc

Answer (score 0):

There's not much information, but you probably need to replace your link with something like this:

```
index.php?option=com_searchtour&task=searchtour.edit_one&cid=<?php echo $order['id'];?>"><?php echo $order['username']
```

Even though Joomla will rewrite to what you have above using the `task=`runs additional methods in Joomla so it knows what to do.